# normalize 3D object using minimum bounding sphere

Tags: matlab, 3d, normalization

On the PhD thesis of Thibault [thesis from here](http://vision.isen-bretagne.fr/~napoleon/documents/research/PHD_Thibault_Napoleon.pdf), I have read that we can normalize 3D objects based on minimum bounding sphere. So that the descriptor applied can handl scale and translation variance. First, they compute the minimum bounding sphere to get the center `C(cx,cy,cz)` and the radius R. So the parametres of the transofrmation ToS (Translation and Scale) are defined like this `(1/R,cx,cy,cz)`, and allow to normlize that object by fiting it in a unit sphere such that each vertice become : `v(x = (x'-cx)/R, y = (y'-cy)/R, z = (z'-cz)/R);`.

My objectif is to implement this with matlab, and I really do not see how can I do it , I mean how can I fitt the object to this unit spher to be normalized to obtaine somthing like this : [normalized bject using minimum bounding sphere](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jFygy.png), I need your help pleaz. thank you.

Comment: Do you have the bounding sphere? Do you have the object coordinates? Have you tried coding the equations? It's difficult to tell from your question where exactly your problem is.

Comment: Hi I am sorry to respond too late but yes I tried and I found the solution, it was just an error when multiplying by R instead of 1/R. It seems that I am beginning to be more familiarised with matlab. thank you.